# update the nested object within struts2

Tags: struts2, nested

With struts2,it will automaticlly create the bean in our action through the ognl,it is easy to use it when we create a new object,for example,in  user register page,we build a form for use to fill their information,and in the action we get the properties populated bean,we can save it directly(maybe need some validation),it is so easy.

But how about update a existed object in the db?

We can build a form,(prepopulate the properties that can be updated in the page),when user make some modifination,we update it.

But the bean we get in the action is created by struts2(we call this bean as bean_struts2),and what we want to updated is in the db(we call this bean bean_db).

Now the problem is how to copy the modifinations of the bean_struts2 to bean_db?

For a non-nested object,we can iterator all the properties of the bean_struts2,and set it to bean_db.

For example:

```
bean_db.setPassword(bean_struts2.getPassword());
.....
```

But it does not so easy when the bean to be updated is a nested object.

In my case,these are the entities:

```
class Task{
    Object non_updatedProperty;
    List<TaskSteps> steps;
    List<User> managers;
    User publisher;
}
class User{
    id,name;
}
class TaskStep{
    id,name;
    List<Operator> operators;
    TaskStepStatus status;
}
enum TaskStepStatus{
    ongoing,completed.
}
class Operator{
    id,name;
}
```

The bean to be updated is the "Task" object.

In the page:

```
<s:form action="task_update" namespace="/common" cssStyle="width:95%">
    <s:textfield value="%{task.id}" cssStyle="display:none" name="task.id"></s:textfield>
    <s:textfield value="%{task.publisher.name}" readonly="true" label="Publisher"></s:textfield>
    <s:textfield name="task.name" value="%{task.name}" label="Task Name"/>
    <table>
        <caption align="left">Steps</caption>
        <tr>
            <th>Step Name</th>
            <th>Operators</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Set order</th>
            <th><span id="addStep" style="cursor:pointer" >Add a step</span></th>
        </tr>
        <s:iterator value="task.steps">
            <tr class="step">
                <td>
                    <s:textfield name="task.steps[0].name" value="%{#this.name}" theme="simple"/>
                    <s:textfield name="task.steps[0].id" value="%{#this.id}" theme="simple" cssStyle="display:none"/>
                </td>
                <td><s:textfield name="task.steps[0].end" value="%{#this.end}" theme="simple"/></td>
                <td>        
                    <s:select list="allOpIndb"  listKey="id" listValue="name" value="%{#this.operator.{id}}"
                        name="task.steps[0].operator.id" multiple="true" theme="simple" id="a">
                    </s:select>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <s:select list="@com.zjswkj.location.entity.TaskStepStatus@values()"  theme="simple" 
                        name="task.steps[0].status" listValue="cnValue" value="%{#this.status}" id="b"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <span class="up">up</span>
                    <span class="down">down</span>
                    <span class="del">del</span>
                </td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </s:iterator>
    </table>
</s:form>
```

Through struts2,I can get the bean_strtus2(Task),its id is the same as the bean_db.
I can easily copy its non-nested propertis to the bean_db. but how about the propertis of its TaskSteps and the operators of its TaskSteps.

Just use :

```
task_db.setTaskSteps(task_struts2.getTaskSteps());??
```

Of course not,this may cause some new TaskStep with the same name persisited to the db.

Also,there are some properties can not be updated,for example,the Task's "non_updatedProperty" property can not be updated,it can only be set when the task are created.

So in the update form,I did not provide a UI to update this property,so if we call:

```
task_db.setNon_updateProperty(task_struts2.getNon_updateProperty);
```

will miss the exist property,beacuse

```
task_struts2.getNon_updateProperty==null; !!!
```

I just wonder if there are some good ideas to handle these types of update?

I am not exactly sure if you guys know what I am meaning,but I have try my best to express it.

If there are more questions,I can update it still.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About the question of transferring efficiently informations from a "structure" (a nested set of beans) managed at the presentation layer (so to say here, populated by Struts2) to another "structure" at the service or the "DB" level, I suggest to have a serious look at http://dozer.sourceforge.net

About the problem of passing on value modification of a "structure" from then to the DB through the presentation layer, it highly depends on the way you map your DB tables (I suppose you're using some kind of relational database) to objects.

When using Hibernate for instance, it is sometimes possible to simply create POJO straight out from your presentation beans, and tell hibernate to "store it"; Hibernate would create / update / delete appropriate records in the table according to the passed structure.
Although most of the times there is no silver bullet, and some kind of structure comparison between the structure mapped from DB content and the structure mapped from the presentation layer (through dozer for example) is required to guess what has to be added, modified or deleted.

Comment: yes,i use hibernate,each entity I mention above are mapped to a table in the db. You said create pojo,how?? The task can not be pojo. it is nested classs.

Comment: about the "non editable" properties, you may pass them to presentation layer with a <s:hidden name="..."/> so you get them back in the task_struts2 populated structure.

Comment: about the "pojo", if task is "composed" of taskSteps, that is to say a taskStep has no mean independantly, you should use a "cascade=all, delete-orphans" in the hibernate mapping describing the relationship between task and taskSteps entities. Then with dozer you can create easily the task/taskStep nested instances from those created by struts2, and just store it with you hibernate dao layer. Hibernate will compute the appropriate modifications (udpates, deletions and creation of sub-entities)

Comment: Yes,I can get the Task object created by struts(this task object contain the taskSteps which are also created by struts),the problem is that I have to copy some (not all) properties from this task object to the related object in the db.No matter I use dozer or beanutils,I have to decide which property should be copyed ,which should be not. I just wonder if all the update-related logic are all so complex?

Comment: To sum up, you need to kinda merge the nested structure coming back from struts2 into the nested structure obtained from the database, but for a particular "subset" of the structure only, those you "picked up" from the whole nested structure when you built the input page. I'm afraid I know no magic bullet for that, as I don't see a standard way to represent this subset.

Comment: So,what is the regular way you use for these kind of operation,I mean update something?